# GDB: unable to read symbols

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, gdb

When trying to run my iOS app on a device, I get the following from GDB, and resulting in my app exiting just right after it started so I never get the chance to debug it. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or what I can do to fix it?

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1470) (Thu May 27 05:54:06 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys002
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: Unable to read symbols from "dyld" (prefix __dyld_) (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "(null)/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "UIKit" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "Foundation" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "(null)/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreGraphics" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "AudioToolbox" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libgcc_s.1.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libSystem.B.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "libobjc.A.dylib" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "CoreFoundation" (not yet mapped into memory).
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-4572-43
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
gdb stack crawl at point of internal error:
/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1470/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-dyld.c:1547: internal-error: unrecognized shared library breakpoint
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
0   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0013117d internal_vproblem + 316
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem at the moment, but I believe it is to do with your frameworks. 
Maybe try removing them and re-adding them to your project. Sorry I couldn't be more help, if I find a solution I will let you know.

*EDIT

Ignore the whole framework issue, the real problem is your IOS on your development screen. Make sure you have the latest version and that this matches your iphone's IOS.